# Heroku build fails with public GitHub repo as dependency

Tags: npm, heroku

It builds completely fine locally but on Heroku it keeps hitting same error ([log provided](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QGqo_wFEsmDvS0hNNDN2n8yTX5-qqt5e/view?usp=sharing)). Already tried a few solutions but finally coming here for help. One suggested editing the package-lock.json which did not solve the issue.

```
"package": "https://github.com:user/repo.git",
"package": "git://github.com:user/repo.git",
"package": "git@github.com:user/repo.git",
```

None of the above is building.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

it tries to perform npm install with node 16.13.0 on linux server. what node version and platform are you using locally ?

also try remove package-lock.json totally.

the errors in the log are probably related to package-lock.json that was created using different version of node than the one it build on the server ( 16.13 )

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I deleted the package-lock.json file and also updated to latest stable version of node and I'm now also getting the issue locally. I am following what is mentioned in the docs so not sure why this is an issue: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#git-urls-as-dependencies

Comment: so if you want to go back to the successfull setup, revert back to previous node version you used when the build was successfull, and instruct Heroku to use the same node version ( in package.json https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#engines )